# Identify duplicates with multiple holdings

Tags: python, pandas

I have one list of dictionaries `List1` in the format {Account Name: { Stock Name: Stock Allocations}}, such as the following:

```
List1 =[{'A001':{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}}, {'A002':{'ABC':0.5, 'ABD':0.4, 'EFG':0.1}}, {'A003':{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}}, {'A004':{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}}]
```

`{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}` occurs three times as a value in three accounts A001, A003, and A004.

I used this code to get values:

```
AccountName = []
for account in List1: 
    for key, value in account.items():
        AccountName.append(value)
```

How can I display duplicates for each account as below? such as

```
Account Name   Duplicate(s) 
A001           A003, A004
A002           No duplicate     
A003           A001, A004
A004           A001, A003
```

Comment: please rectify the list of dictionaries, seems not correct

Comment: you asked this about half an hour ago and were told to try pandas `groupby` and report difficulties you run into

Comment: I deleted the other one and make it more right to the point. I was able to use `groupby` to get the list. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi anky_91, I have rectified the list. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following snippet:

```
res = [] 
for idx, item in enumerate(list1): 
    account_name = list(item.keys())[0] 
    value = list1[idx][account_name] 
    duplicates = ", ".join([list(i.keys())[0] for i in list1 if i[list(i.keys())[0]] == value and list(i.keys())[0] != account_name]) 
    if not duplicates: 
        duplicates = "No duplicates" 
    res.append((account_name, duplicates))
```

Comment: Thanks and it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create another dictionary with key as a value of other dictionaries and values of that dictionary is a set of keys of that dictionary. Basically, you revert your dictionary where keys are values and values are set of keys. So if you have the same values your keys for those values will be part of that key.

Here is how one_dict looks like after conversion:

```
{(('ABC', 0.4), ('ABD', 0.6)): {'A003', 'A001', 'A004'},
 (('ABC', 0.5), ('ABD', 0.4), ('EFG', 0.1)): {'A002'}})
```

Then it is just matter of itterating and printing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [
    {"A001": {"ABC": 0.4, "ABD": 0.6}},
    {"A002": {"ABC": 0.5, "ABD": 0.4, "EFG": 0.1}},
    {"A003": {"ABC": 0.4, "ABD": 0.6}},
    {"A004": {"ABC": 0.4, "ABD": 0.6}},
]

one_dict = defaultdict(set)
for r in list1:
    one_dict[tuple([*r.values()][0].items())].add([*r.keys()][0])

print(f"{'Account Name':<15}{'Duplicates'}")
for k, v in one_dict.items():
    for i in v:
        print(f"{i:<15}{', '.join(v - {i}) if 1 < len(v) else 'No duplicate'}")
```

Output:

```
Account Name   Duplicates
A001           A003, A004
A003           A001, A004
A004           A001, A003
A002           No duplicate
```

Comment: Thanks and it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the list being one-entry dictionaries make processing more cumbersome than necessary.  If you only ever have one account per element in the list, you should make them tuples (account,allocations) instead.

converting List1 to that format (allocs variable) makes the code mode straightforwart:

```
List1  = [{'A001':{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}}, {'A002':{'ABC':0.5, 'ABD':0.4, 'EFG':0.1}}, {'A003':{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}}, {'A004':{'ABC':0.4, 'ABD':0.6}}]

allocs = [ list(account.items())[0] for account in List1]
for account,alloc in allocs:
    dups = [ac for ac,al in allocs if al == alloc and ac != account]
    print( account, ", ".join(dups or ["no duplicates"]))


A001 A003, A004
A002 no duplicates
A003 A001, A004
A004 A001, A003
```

Comment: Thanks and it is very helpful.